# Convert an arc to graphicPath

Tags: c#, system.drawing

think we have a graphicPath , and we create a arc in there like here

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddBezier(
```

Now I want to get an array of points that Bezier was created , how can I get that points ?  is it possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I think you need is call `Flatten` on your graphics path, and then get the `PathPoints`.

Flatten will discretize the path into straight line pieces, according to the docs.

See [the docs on Flatten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327348%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). This overload allows you to specifiy the granularity, if you don't need to transform the points you can pass an identity matrix.